# Rendering every other frame to 29.97fps

Tags: rendering, animation, frame-rate

I am animating to an audio file that is 29.97s(Standard frame rate). but I want my animation to have a look as it if were animated at 12 fps, not slowing down but dropping frames.

From what I found in the render properties, changing the frame rate will change the speed of my whole animation and time remapping isn't giving me the result I want.

Comment: you can change the speed of your animation in the video sequencer

Comment: I changed my description to clarify, I'm trying to drop frames without changing the speed of my animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the Dimensions, in the Output properties, you can change the Step value, to 2. Then render your video, or image sequence. That way, it will only render every other frame. Then you can add the image sequence, (or video), back into Blender, and then add a speed control to it. Then grab the end handle, and drag out, to make it longer, so that its the length you want. In this case, I believe you would make the video double as long, to make it the same length as it originally was, to fit the audio.
Hope this helps!

Comment: This works while it isn't as ideal for me as rendering it directly as video. Thanks Ryan. Keep up the videos btw.

Comment: Oh, you've seen my videos? Cool, thanks!!   : )

Comment: Yeah! and you commented on my Wallace and Gromit video once lol.